# How to get rid of the root with complex expression

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have little problm to solve and if there is some complex analysis master, any help is appreciated.

I have to solve this equation.
$\sin^2(z) = i\pi$. Considering that my domain is the complex plane, there is no any kind of restrictions. I difference squares and in the and for the first solution I got in my equation as a part this expression. $\sqrt{1-i\pi}$. I know that there is a way to get rid of square root by adding some elements to this equation, but i can't remember how. I don't want to have any complex expression under the root, i.e. if I want to solve this equation I need to split real part of my expression and imaginary. How could I do that with this root?

Comment: Have you considered a half-angle formula?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{i} = (1+i)/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the connection between the complex cosine-function and the complex exponential function. $$\cos 2z = \frac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}}{2}$$ and use the formula $$\cos 2z = 1 - 2\sin^2z\ .$$ 
Introducing $w = e^{2iz}$ the equation $\sin^2z = i\pi$ becomes a polynomial equation in $w\ .$ $$w^2 - 2w(1-2i\pi) + 1 = 0\ .$$

Comment: Thank you. I made cardinal mistake, working with sin(z) and square roots of (iπ). This makes everything easier. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are most welcome. I'm happy to have helped.